# LDO and buck converter

Tags: buck, ldo

I heard someone said, using LDO is better than buck converter, but I don't know why.

Why is an LDO better to be used with op-amps than a buck converter?

Comment: Go back to the person and ask them in what context they made that statement. Ask them to justify it. The answer is dependent on the type of application circuit being considered and "used with op-amps" is too broad.

Comment: @Andyaka  Usually the LDO efficiency is better than buck converter? I mean 5V to 3.3V this applictaion. 
I see someone use Buck to do 5V-3.3V, and someone use LDO. 
I will go back to ask them

Comment: @Jerry LDO has terrible efficiency but at low currents the efficiency may not matter as buck converters may also have terrible efficiency at low currents. Buck converter is needed to get better efficiency with high currents. So it depends on required current, cost, complexity, PCB area, heat generation etc which is better in which case.

Comment: @Justme I got it thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First it is important to understand the difference between a classical linear regulator and a low-dropout version. The term LDO is often used for any linear regulator but all regulators are not LDOs. As you know, a linear regulator can only drop the input voltage. As such, the input voltage \$V_{in}\$ must be higher than the output voltage \$V_{out}\$ to ensure a good regulation mechanism. By how much shall it be higher then? Let's look at the input stage of both structures:

[image]

These pictures are excerpted from an [article](https://archive.eetasia.com/www.eetasia.com/ARTICLES/2000DEC/2000DEC08_AMD_AN2.PDF?SOURCES=DOWNLOAD) I published in EDN many years ago during the glorious MOT times. In the left side, for instance considering the venerable MC7805, the series-pass element is a NPN. You know that for properly biasing it, its base must be higher than the emitter by a \$V_{be}\$ which amounts to 0.65 V. If you add the 200-mV saturation voltage of the driving PNP, then for a 5-V output, the input voltage should at least be 5.85 V. For a battery-operated system, you can imagine that you are losing autonomy considering the low-level limit to deliver a stable 5 V.

If rather than using an NPN you implement a PNP as in the right-side picture, the situation differs as biasing the transistor now requires pulling its base down, lower than the emitter by a \$V_{be}\$: the lower limit on the input voltage benefits from this arrangement. Typical LDO drops depend on the structure but 140 mV at a 300-mA output current is no uncommon these days.

The below picture excerpted from this nice [application note](https://www.analog.com/media/en/analog-dialogue/volume-41/number-2/articles/low-dropout-regulators.pdf) shows the type of series-pass elements now used in recent regulators. Most of them are now using P-channel devices.

[image]

To obtain such low drop like 140 mV at a 300-mA current, it implies that the series-pass element offers a quite small resistance like 0.5 ohm or so in this example. You can imagine that ensuring a good input voltage rejection is a challenge in this case where the transistor is almost saturated. And that is the important point: the closer you operate the LDO to its minimum voltage drop, the more difficult it becomes to ac-isolate the output from input perturbations. Semiconductor vendors rival in clever circuits to offer an excellent line rejection (power supply rejection ratio, PSRR) even in the almost-saturated mode in which the transistor operates. As a conclusion, if you want a good isolation brought by the linear regulator, operate it with a sufficiently-large drop (considering power dissipation is not at stake of course) to offer the best rejection. And in this case, a classical linear regulator will do the job and it does not have necessarily to be a LDO type.

Regarding efficiency, again it depends on the difference between input and output voltages. If we consider that the bias currents necessary to operate the regulator are negligible with respect to the output current, then the efficiency solely depends on the difference between \$V_{in}\$ and \$V_{out}\$:

[image]

A quick calculation shows the efficiency curve and two different application examples:

[image]

Surprisingly, if you supply a 7812 by a 13-V source, the efficiency can theoretically peak to 92.3%. Use an LDO and reduce the drop to 150 mV, then efficiency increases to \$\frac{12}{12.15}\$ which is more than 98%. Not bad for a linear regulator!

Now, what about the buck converter? The below slide is an excerpt from my [tutorial](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202019.pdf) seminar taught at an APEC conference in 2019 and compares a buck with a linear regulator:

[image]

You can see that the main difference between them despite efficiency comparison is the noise available on the output. A buck is intrinsically more noisy than a linear regulator because of the currents and voltages chopped at the switching frequency. There is not much you can do about and efficient filtering via cascaded filters is what it takes to reduce the output ripple. There are architectures noisier than others (hard versus soft switching for instance) but if noise is of concern for supplying sensitive circuits, then yes, a linear regulator is the way to go.

Comment: Sir, why the Io can equal Iin, 
If we consider that the bias currents necessary to operate the regulator are negligible with respect to the output current, what that mean

Comment: It is an approximation for a linear regulator: if the output current is 1 A while the bias currents for the internals amount to 10 mA, then you have \$I_{in} \approx I_{out}\$.

Answer (score 1):

That is a broad statement, but since the context is nothing more that just powering op-amps, a simple answer is that buck converters have switcing noise on their output which the LDO does not.

So using LDO for powering op-amps results in less ripple and noise on the signal processed by the op-amp.